# using jquery files as dependency for react app - getting error

Tags: jquery, reactjs, plugins

i am trying to use imgNotes in react app.
but I am getting an error.
although the jquery part is working, it's the imgNotes part where I am getting the error.
Maybe I didnt include it properly .
please tell me where am I going wrong with this.

here's the library I want to use - https://github.com/waynegm/imgNotes
and here's the codesandbox where I am using it - https://codesandbox.io/s/5xkvny1v3l

I am getting the error `TypeError: this.$imagez.imgNotes is not a function`

okay, I think I am getting the dependency but am unable to access it properly.
I found out now that imageNotes is available at window.$.fn.imgNotes.
but not sure how to use it as a function here.
i am trying to do `var imgNotes = window.$.fn.imgNotes;`
But i am unable to use it like this `this.$imagez.imgNotes();`

how do i access it and use it properly?